# Good shiur on Issur Vehetar for semicha?

Tags: product-recommendation, adult-learning, semicha, yoreh-deah, issur-vheter

I'm looking for clear and concise shiurim on Issur Vehetar that gives a summary of the Shulchan aruch with Shach and Taz to aide in my smicha studies.

I see there are many shiurim on yutorah but I couldn't seem to find any that fit my description.

Please let me know what has worked for you. (Preferably free of charge)

Comment: There are many different styles on YUTorah, but very few that are seif by seif. Try YouTube for a few that are like that. Hebrew and English shiurim by R' Ofer Livnat, some guy in Kochav Yaakov, and some others come to mind as what you're looking for. Try also Kol HaLoshon.

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/65374

Answer (score 2):

The [Pirkei Shoshanim](https://pirchei-shoshanim.teachable.com/) programme provides a comprehensive semicha with shiurim online.

The issur v'heter series [here](https://pirchei-shoshanim.teachable.com/p/issur-v-heter) is delivered by Rabbi Chaim Smulowitz.

The site writes about him:

> Rabbi Chaim Smulowitz learned in Yeshiva Torah Vadaas under Rav Avraham Pam and Rav Eliezer Kahanah Ztz”l and Ybl”c Rav Yisrael Belsky Shlita. He received Semicha from Rav Pam.
>
> He is currently a Senior member of the Detroit’s Lakewood Kollel (under Rav Shmuel Irons and Rav Yitzchok Schwab Shlita.) He is also Shoel Umeishiv of the Daf Hashavua program in Detroit.
>
> He has authored a “Gemara and Tosfos” series of English E-sefarim explaining Tosfos.

The programme contains a two-part series on melicha, a three part series on basar b'chalav and a three part series on ta'aruvos.

There is however a cost to the programme of 15 payments of $118.80 per month but there are free previews available, for example [here](https://pirchei-shoshanim.teachable.com/courses/issur-v-heter/lectures/10414402) (you'll notice there that there is also an accompanying daf mekoros to go with the video, along with an overview of the mefarshim and Q&As), in each section so you can see if it is right for you before signing on.

Comment: I personally like the content and have had success with it, and so have friends of mine. if Dov did not post this answer, I would have.